# Audiowaveform Permission denied bbcrd

Tags: php, git, shell, audio, waveform

Im using this  https://github.com/bbcrd/audiowaveform library.
Everything is installed correctly (using build git method not apt) 
When im trying to run `audiowaveform -i test.mp3 -o test.dat -z 256 -b 8` in **terminal** it **works fine**.

When im trying to run the same thing in php using exec

```
$cmd = "audiowaveform -i  /var/www/html/test.mp3 -o /var/www/html/test.dat -z 256 -b 8"; 
$cmd .= " 2>&1 ";
exec($cmd,$error); 
var_dump($error);
```

It shows this error

```
...
Done: 99%
Done: 100%
[11] => Recoverable frame level error: lost synchronization
[12] => 
[13] => Frames decoded: 13921 (6:03.650)
[14] => Generated 62645 points
[15] => Failed to write data file: /var/www/html/test.dat
[16] => Permission denied
```

Looks like some permission error any help ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run from command line, you're executing with your user privileges. When running from web server, the username is different with different permissions. The user is usually `www-data`

First create the file if it doesn't exist so you can set permissions

```
touch /var/www/html/test.dat
```

To give permission to anyone

```
chmod 777 /var/www/html/test.dat
```

Or you can change owner to the web server user

```
chown www-data /var/www/html/test.dat
```

The best way is probably to add the group, so only you two can write

```
chown :www-data /var/www/html/test.dat
chmod 775 /var/www/html/test.dat
```

Comment: silly mistake forgot to set www-data as owner thanks anyway